# Why are users not imported inside Keycloak Docker container?

Tags: docker, keycloak, quay.io

I am trying to import a realm with users from one docker container into another. I exported the realm successfully using

```
./kc.sh export --dir export/ --realm test
```

This command now creates some file

```
test-realm.json
test-users-0.json
test-users-1.json
```

I then copy the files into the other docker container without a problem.

Now in the other container I simply run

```
./kc.sh import --dir export/
```

This results in the realm being created but without any users. What am I doing wrong? I found that if I manually put all users into the realm file it works, but this approach breaks after ~10k users because keycloak just hangs on import.

Comment: How are you copying the data into the new container? If via a `Dockerfile` can you share that? If via e.g. a volume or bind-mount can you provide the command used to start the contain?

Comment: the copy command is simply `docker cp test-realm.json keycloak:/opt/keycloak/bin/`

Comment: I assume you're copying them around manually after that as dir `export` won't exist under `/opt../bin`. Can you provider more context? The docker image you are using? The output logs from the container?